# Commutative Property of SELECT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

Commutative property describes itself as for example a(b*c) = (a*b)c.
Considering this example, how can we get commutative relation from SELECT statement in MySQL particularly. So far, I am clearly unable to execute the following query.

```
SELECT name from (
  SELECT name from employee WHERE id = 5;
)
```

Comment: You need to provide an alias name in the derived query `SELECT name from (
  SELECT name from employee WHERE id = 5
)x`

Comment: It worked! but what's the reason behind providing alias name?

Comment: When you do a select from a derived table mysql needs every derived table to be given an unique alias name.

Comment: That's associative, not commutative.